# How can you replace the single-use access tokens in an action-xhr header without using amp-bind?

Tags: amp-email

### Problem

How is it possible to insert a new token (that's returned in the response) into the `action-xhr`, if we can't use `amp-bind`?

### Background

From the Gmail markup docs on [Limited Use Access Tokens](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/actions/limited-use-access-tokens), requests should be signed with an object ID and a unique token.

```
http://www.example.com/approve?requestId=123&accessToken=xyz
```

This combination of id + token should be used once. The docs state:

> Once this request gets through, any future request with the same id and access token should be rejected too

After completing a successful request, we need to create a new token for a subsequent write.

However, the [AMP for Email docs](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/develop/amp_email_best_practices/) indicate that we can't change the `action-xhr` for a `<form>` tag:

> The src attribute of amp-list, action-xhr of amp-form, the src for amp-img, or the href attribute of an  tag cannot be mutated by amp-bind.

Answer (score 0):

[Limited Use Access Tokens](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/actions/limited-use-access-tokens) is for the [Email Markup](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup) feature, which is unrelated to AMP for Email. The documentation recommends rejecting "future request with the same id and access token" probably due to the nature of the [One Click Actions](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/one-click-action) feature, where the actions rendered from the markup are mostly one-time action that shouldn't be done repeatedly:

> `ConfirmAction` can only be interacted with once.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/one-click-action#confirm_action

> `SaveAction` can only be interacted with once.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/one-click-action#save_action

This is in contrast to the [Go-To Actions](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/go-to-action) feature, where the action can be done multiple times, although obviously only recommended for a simple link without any mutation of states.

There's no such universal recommendation for AMP for Email. It's up to the email sender whether certain actions will be rejected after the first success or can be done repeatedly. You are right that the AMP for Email format doesn't even allow generating dynamic access tokens from within the email, so if the email sender rejects the request after the first success, the sender should probably render some kind of error message (e.g., by using a `<div submit-error>` element under `amp-form`) if the user tries to perform some action for a second time. The access token should be hardcoded in the URL of the original email payload. It should still be for limited use by expiring it after 30 days or less.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However, the official [AMP for Email Fundamentals](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/email_fundamentals/?format=email) docs have the same information (search for "Limited Use Access Tokens"). Is this a mistake? If not, it's quite misleading :/

Comment: Thanks for flagging. I've sent https://github.com/ampproject/amp.dev/pull/6330 to clarify.